# Cannot access to PSObject's properties via Commands executed in c# code

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm executing the following command in c# coded program. But it behaves different while executing it locally and executing by remoting feature.

The code for executing it locally:

```
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace))
        {
            ps.AddCommand("Get-IISAppPool")
              .AddParameter("Name", "MyCustomAppPool");
            var results = ps.Invoke();

            var appPool = results.FirstOrDefault();
            var processModel = PSObject.AsPSObject(appPool.Properties["ProcessModel"].Value);
            var userName = processModel.Properties["UserName"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(username);
        }
```

The code for executing it remotely:

```
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace))
        {
            ps.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://localhost:5985/wsman")));
            ps.Runspace.Open();

            ps.AddCommand("Get-IISAppPool")
              .AddParameter("Name", "MyCustomAppPool");
            var results = ps.Invoke();

            var appPool = results.FirstOrDefault();
            var processModel = PSObject.AsPSObject(appPool.Properties["ProcessModel"].Value);
            //The following line throws NullReferenceException ...
            var userName = processModel.Properties["UserName"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(username);
        }
```

The first code sample is executing very well. But, on the second one I'm getting the NullReferenceExcepiton. And the reason is;

```
appPool.Properties["ProcessModel"].Value
```

on the first case the code above returns the object of type Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPoolProcessModel but on the second case the code above returns string value of "Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPoolProcessModel".

Really strange but when I execute the following script instead it is working fine

```
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace))
        {
            ps.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://localhost:5985/wsman")));
            ps.Runspace.Open();

            ps.AddScript(@"$sss = Get-IISAppPool -Name MyCustomAppPool
            Export-Clixml -inputobject $sss -literalpath C:\mycustomapppool.xml
            $sss = Import-clixml -literalpath C:\mycustomapppool.xml
            return $sss");
            var results = ps.Invoke();

            var appPool = results.FirstOrDefault();
            var processModel = PSObject.AsPSObject(appPool.Properties["ProcessModel"].Value);
            //The following line throws NullReferenceException ...
            var userName = processModel.Properties["UserName"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(username);
        }
```

So, what's the problem here? Can you please help? Looks like there is a problem with deserialization.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, remote connections are not fully serialized by default. You can add `?serializationLevel=Full` to the URI to get the complete objects (also serializing whole object is slow, so take this into account if you indeed to run Powershell on many objects).

Comment: Well @towel ; I'm afraid that it didn't worked either even if I changed the url into "http://localhost:5985/wsman?serializationLevel=Full". Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was so used to work with [Powershell problems on Exchange](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/159771e3-699d-4270-ba27-cd74d28ea0b7/serialization-depth-on-remote-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) that I completely overlooked you were talking about IIS...